# how to get the variable inside a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, function, width

I am trying to get the width of an image by using the following code below, but the problem is, I can't retrive the variable that is inside the function.

```
var get_image_h_w = new Image();
var width;
                        get_image_h_w.onload = function() {
                          width = get_image_h_w.width;
                        }
                        get_image_h_w.src = img_link_url;

alert(width);
```

Comment: Can you make sure the onload function is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.onload` handler will execute some time later, after your `alert(width)` runs.  It will set the variable `width` when it runs, but the ONLY reliable way to know when that occurs is to put the code that wants to use that `width` value in the `onload` handler or call it from the `onload` handler.  This is an example of an asynchronous callback which means it happens "out of sync" with the rest of your code when the event occurs.

```
var get_image_h_w = new Image();
get_image_h_w.onload = function() {
    alert(this.width);
    // you can call some code here that wants to use this width
    // and pass the width to that function
    callYourFunction(this.width);
}
get_image_h_w.src = img_link_url;
```

Note: I also switched to use `this.width` where `this` is the object that created the `onload` event.  That doesn't do something different than the way you had it, but it is more generally usable, particularly when you want the same event handler to work for multiple objects so it's a good practice to use.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `width` is, most likely, never going to hold the image width when you call alert because the onload event does not halt execution until firing.  You are simply assigning a function to the onload event.  The onload event is not going to fire right away.  It instead fires when the image has completed loading, which may be well after execution has reached your call to alert.

Try putting a callback function in the onload event which would use the newly set variable.

```
get_image_h_w.onload = function() {
    width = get_image_h_w.width;
    finishedLoading();
}

var finishedLoading = function () {
   var w = width; // width will be set here
}
```